# How are threads reused in Asp Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, tcp, websocket, c#-7.3

Hello i am building an tcp server where i will have multiple clients connected that will send and receive data to the server.

I want to  know if the framework does not create a **1:1** **Thread** to **Client** ratio but uses the **threadpool** how do the following happen:

**1**.If the method that gets executed after accepting the socket contains a loop inside it, won't the allocated thread (by the threadpool) get blocked on a client context?
**2**.Where is the context for each client stored?

[image]

**P.S** In my picture i do not understand how the blue thread (given by the threadpool to service the two clients)gets reused.

The code below contains the  `Handler` (contains all connections) and the `Client` (a socket wrapper , with basic read/write functionality).

**Sockets Handler**

```
  class Handler
            {

                private Dictionary<string, Client> clients = new Dictionary<string, Client>();
                private object Lock = new object();

                public Handler()
                {

                }
                public async Task LoopAsync(WebSocketManager manager)
                {
                    WebSocket clientSocket = await manager.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
                    string clientID = Ext.MakeId();
                    using(Client newClient = Client.Create(clientSocket, clientID))
                    {
                        while (newClient.KeepAlive)
                        {
                            await newClient.ReceiveFromSocketAsync();
                        }

                    }


                }
                public  bool RemoveClient(string ID)
                {
                    bool removed = false;
                    lock (Lock)
                    {
                        if (this.clients.TryGetValue(ID, out Client client))
                        {
                            removed= this.clients.Remove(ID);
                        }
                    }
                    return removed;

                }

            }
```

**SocketWrapper**

```
class Client:IDisposable
    {
        public static Client Create(WebSocket socket,string id)
        {
            return new Client(socket, id);
        }
        private readonly string ID;
        private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 100;


        private readonly byte[] Buffer;
        public bool KeepAlive { get; private set; }
        private readonly WebSocket socket;


        private Client(WebSocket socket,string ID)
        {
            this.socket = socket;
            this.ID = ID;
            this.Buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        }
        public async  Task<ReadOnlyMemory<byte>> ReceiveFromSocketAsync()
        {   
            WebSocketReceiveResult result = await this.socket.ReceiveAsync(this.Buffer, CancellationToken.None);
            this.KeepAlive = result.MessageType==WebSocketMessageType.Close?false:true;
            return this.Buffer.AsMemory();
        }

        public async Task SendToSocketAsync(string message)
        {
            ReadOnlyMemory<byte> memory = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
            await this.socket.SendAsync(memory, WebSocketMessageType.Binary,true,CancellationToken.None);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.socket.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

The **service** that will get injected in the application:

```
class SocketService
    {
        Handler hander;
        public SocketService(Handler _handler)
        {
            this.hander = _handler;
        }
        RequestDelegate next;

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (!context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {
                await  this.next(context);
                return;
            }
            await this.hander.AddClientAsync(context.WebSockets);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered using SignalR?

Comment: I have but i need full-duplex communication at all times.

Comment: What is the question anwyay? Tasks aren't threads, they are a promise that something will complete in the future. `await` doesn't create any new threads, it *awaits* for an already executing asynchronous operation to complete. Asynchronous network calls may never use threads anyway as IO is asynchronous at the OS level.

Comment: If you want to know how many threads are used by your application, start debugging it, create eg 100 clients it and after a while hit `Pause` and check the `Parallel Stacks` debug window. By definition asynchronous operations *don't* use threads - when an IO operation starts the Windows OS itself releases the caller and calls back into it when a response arrives. Blocking is actually *emulated* to make single-threaded programming easier. Some libraries fake asynchronous operations though and use a blocked thread to wait for responses

Comment: In other cases a high-level operation could be implemented asynchronously only in part. The library may choose to use a thread from a threadpool to perform the rest of the call in the background. Or the library could queue requests and execute them using a limited number of threads. You can't guess how your application will perform by looking at the `await` calls, you need to check the [Websocket.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.WebSockets/src/System/Net/WebSockets/WebSocket.cs) code itself, or debug the application and check the Parallel Stacks

Comment: PS: your code has a serious issue due to that `lock()`. It doesn't matter how many threads to serve clients when you *block* them. Use a `ConcurrentDictionary` instead of locking

Comment: I wanted more like an explanatation how do threads get reassigned by the thread pool ,and how they do switch context.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian you'll find that in learn.microsoft.com, MSDN Magazine articles going back all the way to 2012 and more. There's a ton of information that can't be reproduced in an SO answer. Besides, threads don't get reassigned. When you *submit* a function that needs executing the runtime will pick a thread from the pool. When the function terminates, the thread is put back in the pool

Comment: So should i close the question then if its too broad ?

Comment: Check Stephen Cleary's article [Async Programming : Introduction to Async/Await on ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx). The section `What About the Thread Doing the Asynchronous Work?`  is more or less what you ask for

Comment: I understand the async-await model (the state-machine that gets created for every async method ...etc) i wanted to find out more about synchronization contexts of threads.